# Why isn't pseudo-element content being replaced by more specific declarations?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I've got this `<ul>` set up with pseudo-element icons before each item. Font Awesome's check mark icon is set as the default for every `<li>`, but I want to use specific icons for certain items based on their ID (or class. That doesn't seem to work either). But the specific icon `content` declaration doesn't appear to override the default one, even though the selector should be more specific. Here's a quick example:

```
.cvt-product-tags li:before {
    content: '\f00c'; /* Default checkmark icon */
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
}
      /* Custom per-li icons */
      .cvt-product-tags li#1394:before {
        content: '\f21a'!important; /* Custom boat icon */
      }
      .cvt-product-tags li#1384:before {
        content: '\f207'!important; /* Custom bus icon */
    }
```

I set up a more complete pen over here: https://codepen.io/dimedici/pen/PowGbdv.

The confounding thing is that I had something very similar working before some markup changes wherein the `content` declaration was being properly overridden. What am I doing wrong? Or, more importantly, how do I get it to work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS selectors that start with a number have to be handled in a special manner.

```
.cvt-product-tags li[id='1394']:before {
    content: '\f21a'!important; /* Custom boat icon */
}
 /* The space is important */
.cvt-product-tags li#\31 394:before {
    content: '\f21a'!important; /* Custom boat icon */
}
```

Comment: Ah, heck yeah! Both those solutions work. So the top example is an attribute selector, which I grok. While the bottom... is doing something else.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ethan the bottom is just the way you escape characters in css.

Answer (score 0):

You created issue using `integer` for `ID`. You have to change `id` name `integer` to `string`. i.e.: `#1394` to `#boat-1394`. If you want to use `integer` for `ID` or `Class` then you have to write `CSS` in difference style. i.e.: `[id="1394"]` or `[class="1394"]`.

Check the snippet below.

```css
.container {
  width:26em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.cvt-product-tags {
 -webkit-columns: 2 10em;
 -moz-columns: 2 10em;
 columns: 2 10em;
 -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
 -moz-column-gap: 2em;
 column-gap: 2em;
 margin: 1em 0;
  padding-left:2.1em;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.cvt-product-tags li {
 margin-bottom: .75em;
 line-height: 1.2em;
}
.cvt-product-tags li:before {
 content: '\f00c'; /* Default checkmark icon */
 font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 line-height: 2;
 text-align: center;
 background: #b84542;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0.8em 0 -2.8em;
 width: 2em;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
  /* Custom per-tag icons */
   /* Boat Tour */
   .cvt-product-tags li#boat-1394:before {
    content: '\f21a'!important;
   }
   /* Bus Tour */
   .cvt-product-tags li[id="1384"]:before {
    content: '\f207'!important;
    }
    /* Family Friendly */
    .cvt-product-tags li[id="1377"]:before {
      content: '\f1ae'!important;
    }
    /* Helicopter Tour */
    .cvt-product-tags li[id="1385"]:before {
      content: '\f533'!important;
    }
    /* Meals Included */
    .cvt-product-tags li[id="1378"]:before {
      content: '\f2e7'!important;
    }
    /* Money-back Guarantee */
    .cvt-product-tags li[id="1383"]:before {
      content: '\f53a'!important;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://static.fontawesome.com/css/fontawesome-app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="cvt-product-tags">
    <li id="boat-1394"><a href="/experience-tag/boat-tour/">Boat Tour</a></li>
    <li id="1384"><a href="/experience-tag/bus-tour/">Bus Tour</a></li>
    <li id="1377"><a href="/experience-tag/family-friendly/">Family-Friendly</a></li>
    <li id="1385"><a href="/experience-tag/helicopter-tour/">Helicopter Tour</a></li>
    <li id="1383"><a href="/experience-tag/money-back-guarantee/">Money-back Guarantee</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Gotcha. Those integers were the tag ID that WordPress/WooCommerce assigned to my products' tags. I didn't know that CSS treated integer-only classes and IDs differently. Thanks for the explanation.